# Grafana error: function "humanize" not defined

Tags: grafana, humanize

Saving a custom template with humanize function in it, fails with the following error: `Error: failed to save and apply Alertmanager configuration: template: mytemplate:2: function "humanize" not defined`.

Template contents are:

```
{{ humanize (0.123456) }}
```

Grafana version: 9.5+

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like a correct syntax. Try:

```
{{ humanize 0.123456 }}
```

Doc: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.5/alerting/fundamentals/annotation-label/variables-label-annotation/

Comment: Tried it -- doesn't work. Issue still exists.